# Is normal SPI device compatible with SPI I/F?

Tags: audio, spi, eeprom

Audio controller AK5374 that I use requires EEPROM with SPI. However, in the specs it is written, that it communicates with EEPROM via SPI I/F. Will normal EEPROM be compatible with this interface?

Comment: I/F just means "interface".

Comment: You'll need an SPI storage device compatible with the commands that chip knows how to issue.  Likely what you should do is find a working module or the docs for the eval board they offered, and either use the same SPI chip they used, or use one that seems to have a good match of data sheet details.  Beware if they actually read the chip ID and act accordingly, something compatible but with a different chip ID may not work...   Fortunately those parts tend to have compatible pinouts so you can try a few times until you find one that works.

Comment: The official eval board uses an AK6508CT.  One challenge you may face is that SPI storage devices are usually *flash* not EEPROM, while most EEPROMs are I2C.  AK seems to have made their audio chip use their own less common (but probably not sole-source) idea of an SPI-interface-EEPROM.  But at least there's one part you know works - or would have, as AK have discontinued it with no listed alternative: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/AKM/PD_180406.pdf

Comment: @ChrisStratton "AK seems to have made their audio chip use their own less common (but probably not sole-source) idea of an SPI-interface-EEPROM" - I thought that there is a standard SPI interface for all EEPROMs. Isn't it a case?